# Using a Raspberry Pi to rotate a video

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I want to build a kind of photo booth. A normal booth is so boring so I decided to build a funky fancy one.

I will use 2 Raspberry Pis. One for stream, shoot and print the photo. The other to display the live stream of the photo.

The streaming shooting and printing is already done. Now I am building the video stream display part.

I will show the picture in format 1:1, because i want to display it on every 3 shot rotated by a random angle. So the guys in front of TV have to bend their heads, so I will get strange and funny pictures. Maybe it is possible to rotate constantly like a hypnotic spiral.

On Windows with VLC the rotation of the stream works very well. How can I do this on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a software request? If programming question, what language are you using, what have you figured out already, etc. If a software request, you are probably in the wrong place to ask for it.

Comment: If there is a solution for my problem I will use that.
If not I would try to do my best to program it. 
I have skills in  Python C and Java.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I did it now with HTML and Browser in Fullscreen Mode.

Rotate Videostream and crop it to 1:1